# Trouble installing MySQL client on Mac

Tags: python, macos, mysql-connector

```
 Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz (76 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/mr.sallam/.local/share/virtualenvs/Admission_System-h6ReVRNX/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-install-cn6qvsqm/mysqlclient_c82e6a9eeefe4d66bf9960f11336d0db/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-install-cn6qvsqm/mysqlclient_c82e6a9eeefe4d66bf9960f11336d0db/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-186pdzul
         cwd: /private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-install-cn6qvsqm/mysqlclient_c82e6a9eeefe4d66bf9960f11336d0db/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-install-cn6qvsqm/mysqlclient_c82e6a9eeefe4d66bf9960f11336d0db/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-install-cn6qvsqm/mysqlclient_c82e6a9eeefe4d66bf9960f11336d0db/setup_posix.py", line 47, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/private/var/folders/58/khmzr9l90hx237729cjz2ct00000gn/T/pip-install-cn6qvsqm/mysqlclient_c82e6a9eeefe4d66bf9960f11336d0db/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/91/bdfe808fb5dc99a5f65833b370818161b77ef6d1e19b488e4c146ab615aa/mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=06eb5664e3738b283ea2262ee60ed83192e898f019cc7ff251f4d05a564ab3b7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide some context to your question, like what OS, which version of Python, what previous commands you executed to arrive at this error etc. Simply pasting a snippet of an error does not convey your problem space.

Answer (score 29):

As per the [readme for mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/master/README.md#macos-homebrew), on macOS you will need to install `pkg-config` and `mysql` or `mysql-client`:

> ```
> # Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
> $ brew install mysql pkg-config
> $ pip install mysqlclient
> ```
>
> If you don't want to install MySQL server, you can use mysql-client instead:
>
> ```
> # Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
> $ brew install mysql-client pkg-config
> $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
> $ pip install mysqlclient
> ```

Answer (score 4):

On Mac

```
brew install mysql
```

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered installing [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/), a pure Python MySQL driver?

Also, since it is purely pythonic, it is quite more cross compatible than c based MySQL connectors.

Answer (score -1):

From terminal

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

Comment: Installing MS SQL stuff will not help with MySQL.